# Notepad ++ regex , что-бы вставить текст в <s>CЮДА</s>

Tags: регулярные-выражения, notepad++

Всем ку
У меня 13 листов такого формара

```
<string name="acc">Принято</string> Pieņemts
```

Как содержимое после `</string>` вставлять перед  , удаляя русский перевод

Было

```
<string name="acc">Принято</string> Pieņemts
```

А надо

```
<string name="acc">Pieņemts</string>
```

Таких у меня 13 листов, на каждом где-то 300 переменных, руками задолбаюсь :)

Спасибо

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Как-то так:

```
(<string name="acc">)\w+(</string>) (\w+)
```

```
$1$3$2
```

Comment: дело в том, что <string name="acc"> всенгда будет разный, string name="something", string name="something2" и тд

Comment: @PeterPavlov, `\w+`

Comment: а если  <string name="invite_friend">т.е из 2 слух - \w+\w+ ?

Comment: @PeterPavlov, а если википедию прочитать?

Comment: Понял, спасибо!